# How to pass struct as argument from one contract to another contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I can pass array, uint, bool mappings from one contract to another contract. but I can not pass struct as argument,

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity 0.8.11;

interface SampleInterface {
        struct Point {
                uint256 x;
                uint256 y;
        }
        function setPoint(Point memory) external;
        function getPoint() external view returns(Point memory);
}

contract Sample is SampleInterface {
    Point point;
    function setPoint(Point memory _point) external {
        point = _point;
    }

    function getPoint() external view returns(Point memory) {
        return point;
    }
}
```

This is my source contract. I have deployed the above contract and put the contract address into the following contract to call setPoint and getPoint,

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity 0.8.11;

interface SampleInterface {
    struct Point {
        uint256 x;
        uint256 y;
    }
    function setPoint(Point memory point) external;
    function getPoint() external view returns(Point memory);
}
contract Operator {
    address sample;
    constructor(address _sample) {
        sample = _sample;
    }

    function setPoint(Point memory point) external {
        SampleInterface(sample).setPoint(point);
    }

    function getPoint() external view returns(Point memory) {
        return SampleInterface(sample).getPoint();
    }
}
```

But I am getting the following error,

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Operator.sol

DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
  --> project:/contracts/Operator.sol:18:20:
   |
18 |    function setPoint(Point memory point) external {
   |                      ^^^^^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.5.9 (core: 5.5.9)
Node v12.14.0
```

Help me to fix this issue. How can I call setPoint and getPoint from Operator contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Point` structure doesn't exist in the scope of your contract, only in the interface that you've declared. To fix this issue, you need to use `SampleInterface.Point` instead of `Point`.

```
function setPoint(SampleInterface.Point memory point) external {
    SampleInterface(sample).setPoint(point);
}

function getPoint() external view returns(SampleInterface.Point memory) {
    return SampleInterface(sample).getPoint();
}
```